# How to enabling cut/copy/paste into HTML form in flutter-inappwebview

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I'm developing an app using flutter-inappwebview plugin.  Currently, I'm able to fill mock data into the input text fields. What I want to do is to enable cut/copy/paste into text field if it is disabled by something like oncopy="return false". How can I do that.

This JavaScript code works in chrome but not in the webview.

```
let textElement = document.getElementById('ename')
            textElement.onpaste = ''
            textElement.oncopy = ''
            textElement.oncut = ''
```